# Get folder contents in SublimeText2 plugin

Tags: plugins, package, sublimetext2, sublimetext

At first I want to say I'm a total beginner in Python so this question might be really stupid. I'm currently trying to learn something new and am developing a plugin for SublimeText2.

Can I get a list of files and folders in some directory in `Packages` folder of SublimeText2, what I basically want is a simple list. If yes, how can this be done?

I've searched the [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) for something like that, but the only thing that there is are commands that manipulate the currently open folders (the ones in the sidebar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was really stupid, I won't close the question as I think it may help others to start here. The reason I didn't find anything in SublimeText2 API is because this is the default Python functionality from the `os` library.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os

#...

print(os.listdir(sublime.packages_path()))
```

Method `sublime.packages_path()` returns the path to packages folder.